# Error in .bash_aliases

Tags: bash

```
bash: /root/.bash_aliases: line 73: syntax error near unexpected token `find'
bash: /root/.bash_aliases: line 73: `find ${WP_ROOT} -exec chown ${WP_OWNER}:${WP_GROUP} {} \;'
```

I get that error while sourcing the file.

I have a file that sets the constants and I created a function to execute.

Here is part of it:

```
function chmodwp{
    find ${WP_ROOT} -exec chown ${WP_OWNER}:${WP_GROUP} {} \;
    find ${WP_ROOT} -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
    find ${WP_ROOT} -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
....
}
```

The same "find" line on the bash prompt would work with no problem.  Issue is specific to a function in my aliases file?

I'm on ubuntu 16.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a space between the function name and the opening brace of the function. The following should work:

```
function chmodwp {
  find ${WP_ROOT} -exec chown ${WP_OWNER}:${WP_GROUP} {} \;
  ...
}
```

See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html. Bash in general is somewhat sensitive when it comes to whitespace.

Comment: Wow. You got it. I got to better watch myself ahahah. Thanks a lot.